# Compass sprite images across multiple style sheets

Tags: compass-sass

Is there a way to get compass to generate a sprite sheet from images across different style sheets?

The [tutorial](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) talks about generating sprites from a bunch of images in the folder and then using it in 1 style sheet. But to me, it seems counter intuitive to have to use the following in all my stylesheets that uses the sprite sheet:

```
@import "icon/*.png";
@include all-icon-sprites;
```

I would prefer to have different images set for each sprite sheet, and then some how mark them for sprite generation so that compass can collect them into a sprite and then update the css to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compass only generates one sprite per directory. That's good because it can be cached by browsers eliminating the need to fetch it if you use it on multiple pages. You can use that sprite over and over even selectively using Selector Control which is covered in the tutorial you referenced.

Imagine that in your image folder there are four icons:

- images/icon/apple.png
- images/icon/banana.png
- images/icon/basketball.png
- images/icon/football.png

In a stylesheet called `fruits.sass`, you import all the icons and only use the `apple` and `banana` icons.

```
@import "icon/*.png";

.fruits
  .banana
    +icon-sprite(banana)
  .apple
    +icon-sprite(apple)
```

In a stylesheet called `sports.sass`, you import all the icons and only use `basketball` and `football` icons.

```
@import "icon/*.png";

.sports
  .football
    +icon-sprite(football)
  .basketball
    +icon-sprite(basketball)
```

When you compile, one sprite named something like `icon-sjargon1.png` will be generated in `images`.

- images/icon/apple.png
- images/icon/banana.png
- images/icon/basketball.png
- images/icon/football.png
- images/icon-sjargon1.png

Your generated `fruits.css` will look something like:

```
.icon-sprite,
.fruits .banana,
.fruits .apple { background: url('/images/icon-sjargon1.png') no-repeat; }

.fruits .banana { background-position: 0 -20px; }
.fruits .apple { background-position: 0 0; }
```

Your generated `sports.css` will look like:

```
.icon-sprite,
.sports .football,
.sports .basketball { background: url('/images/icon-sjargon1.png') no-repeat; }

.sports .football { background-position: 0 -60px; }
.sports .basketball { background-position: 0 -40px; }
```

Comment: Perfect and very well written too! :)

Comment: Hmm. The `@import "icon/*.png"` throws up Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "...$main-clean-up,": expected function argument, was ");"
        on line 18 of main
        from line 3 of. I am also using SCSS.

Comment: Upgraded to the latest compass.app and all is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also separate sprites putting images in separate folders.
For example:

```
@import "themeOne/*.png";
@include all-themeOne-sprites;

@import "themeTwo/*.png";
@include all-themeTwo-sprites;
```

This is useful when your site has many sections and a maybe specific section must have a different theme.

One last thing...

I'm not a fan of adding ALL the sprite images with `@include all-themeOne-sprites;`, I prefer to do so:

```
@import "themeOne/*.png";

.somebox .icon {
    @include themeOne-sprite(anyIcon);
}
```

And if you want the `.somebox .icon` to be sized as the anyIcon image, you can add the true parameter after the icon name, like so:

```
.somebox .icon {
    @include themeOne-sprite(anyIcon, true);
}
```

I hope it helps!