# Using multiple stylesheets with a single Compass sprite through import

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to use compass to import and include a sprite and a bunch of partials in one SCSS file and have the included partials get access to the sprite's generated variables/mixins/etc. It's a bit similar to this question: [Compass sprite images across multiple stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285794/compass-sprite-images-across-multiple-style-sheets), but still different enough that I thought I'd ask a new question.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

### all-icons.scss

```
$icon-sprite-dimensions: true;
@import "icon/*.png";
@include all-icon-sprites;

// Include partials
@import "pirate-icons";
@import "ninja-icons";
@import "cowboy-icons";
```

I would like to be able to use the variables and mixins generated from `@import "icon/*.png"` and `@include all-icon-sprites` in the included partials. I don't really want to have to do `@import "icon/*.png"`, etc. in each one of the partials if I don't have to because it will generate duplicate entries in each partial. There are ways to get around this by not using `@include all-icon-sprites` and instead using things like `@include icon-sprite(spurs)`. This isn't ideally what I want to do, but it works. The other thing I don't like is that when you `@import` the sprite into multiple files, you get something like:

```
   create images/icon-s00df19a6f5.png
unchanged images/icon-s00df19a6f5.png
unchanged images/icon-s00df19a6f5.png
unchanged images/icon-s00df19a6f5.png
   create stylesheets/all-icons.css
```

Is there a way for something like this to work in Compass or do I have to `@import "icon/*.png"` in each one of the partials and then use `@include all-icon-sprites` or multiple of these `@include icon-sprite(holster)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel a little silly, but it turns out that this already works perfectly.

You only run into problems when you're including regular sass files and not partials (pirate-icons.scss = regular, _pirate-icons.scss = partial). The reason it doesn't work when those files are not partials is that compass compiles those separately, outside the scope of the file they're being included in, which can result in inconsistencies and errors because those stylesheets no longer know about the sprite variables and mixins when you're trying to use them.

For example, when doing

```
$icon-sprite-dimensions: true;
@import "icon/*.png";
@include all-icon-sprites;

// Include partials
@import "pirate-icons";
@import "ninja-icons";
@import "cowboy-icons";
```

If cowboy-icons was cowboy-icons.scss, it would compile once in the scope of the all-icons.scss file and once outside of that file's scope. When compiling outside that scope, any attempts to use one of the mixins like `@include icon-sprite(spurs)` would cause an error because it doesn't know what that means anymore.

tl;dr

just make sure that pirate-icons is `_pirate-icons.scss` and not `pirate-icons.scss` and it should have the desired effect.

Comment: What I don't like about this approach is that now in each file where you include your icons, the same .icon-sprite{background-image:...} css class is defined across multiple css files. Is there anything I can do about that?